# How to randomly place 2 unique points on a 2D array?

Tags: c++

The picking itself is easy, but I'm having trouble making sure I can't place the points on the same spot. I could of course re-random, but is there a better way? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the application of this? Is there a reason why choosing another set of random coordinates is not acceptable?

Comment: One possibility of random is that you get the same point twice in a row.

Comment: And another possibility is that you get the same point 1000 times in a row (hence just rerolling is not ideal).

Comment: @Ben Voigt: even with a 2x1 matrix the chance (1/2^1000) is astronomically small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

choosing K indices from N possible locations randomly is equivalent to first random shuffling the array and then take the first K indices. If you program in c++ (which is what you are giving as tag), it can be as easy as:

first, make your 2D array flat, say its stored in a vector: vector elems;

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

.... initialize elems to whatever you want, here all zeros ......

vector<int> elems (N*M, 0);

// assigning your indices from 0 to elems.size()-1
vector<int> index (elems.size());
for (int i=0; i<index.size(); i++)
{
    index[i] = i;
}

// now random permute
random_shuffle (index.begin(), index.end());

// now assign the elements to whatever you want, here assign them to 1
elems[index[0]] = 1;
elems[index[1]] = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by linearizing your 2D indices *x,y* to 1D *i*.

Let's assume you have a 2D array of *MxN* size.

Generate a random integer in *[0, MxN)*:

```
int i1 = rand() % (M * N);
```

Your 2D array indices will be:

```
int x1 = i1 % M;
int y1 = i1 / M;
```

Now generate a second 1D index that covers the 2D array but not the one you hit earlier. You can do this by generating a random number in *[0, MxN-1)* and circulating this 1D index by the first generated number:

```
int i2 = (rand() % (M * N - 1) + i1 + 1) % (M * N);
```

These two 1D indices will always be different, of course when *MxN* is not *1x1*.

Your second pair of 2D indices are similarly:

```
int x2 = i2 % M;
int y2 = i2 / M;
```

Comment: the idea is good, but the actual expression for `i2` is just plain wrong.

Comment: getting better but still not quite right ;) hint: shift to next position.

Answer (score 1):

junjanes almost has a solution, but doesn't actually prevent generating the same index twice.

Generate i2 this way instead:

```
int i2 = rand() % (M * N - 1);
if (i2 >= i1) ++i2;
```